# operation not permitted: /dev/nulleval MacOS Ventura 13.0.1

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-ventura

`(eval):3: operation not permitted: /dev/nulleval`

This is the output I am seeing on my macbook with ventura latest update, this caused when I tried installing `git-lfs`.

But not able to get rid of this.

---

Tried the following:

- Going to settings, privacy and giving the full disk access to terminal.
- Hard-Resetting the terminal.

This it the output after I do `ls -ld /dev /dev/null` (if it helps)

OUTPUT:

`dr-xr-xr-x  4 root  wheel       4769 Dec 17 12:30 /dev`

`crw-rw-rw-  1 root  wheel  0x3000002 Dec 17 12:48 /dev/null`

Comment: /dev/nulleval isn't a thing that exists, or should exist. I don't think this is a permissions problem, it's more likely to be due to a typo something in a script somewhere. When exactly do you get this error?

Comment: It just pops when I start terminal.

Comment: Then it's probably something in one of your shell initialization files. If you're using zsh (the default in recent versions of macOS), it'll be ~/.zshrc or ~/.zlogin or ~/.zshenv or ~/.zsomethingelse. If you're using bash, it'll be ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc or something. There are a lot of previous questions about tracking down errors in these files on [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) and the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Do some searching and investigating.

Comment: Tried a few things (including reset settings for bash, uninstalling zsh) still this is unresolved.

Comment: Did you check the files I mentioned? And what do you mean by "reset settings for bash" (deleting those files? Something else?) and "uninstalling zsh" (it's part of the macOS install, not really something you can remove)?